# Python code completion IntelliSense using Singularity container interpreter

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, intellisense, vscode-remote, singularity-container

I have made a file `python` and made it executable `chmod +x python`

```
singularity exec instance://pytorch python "$@"
```

so that I can treat this `python` file as a python binary, passing any parameters passed to it will be delegated to the python installed in the running instance.

Now to make *vscode* point to this interpreter, I had to make `settings.json` inside `.vscode` folder

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "./python"
}
```

It works fine and I am able to run the script directly on this interpreter. But I can't get autocomplete to work. **Why doesn't it work and how do I make it work?**

Comment: It doesn't give you autocompletion because the LSP can't operate from your fake python interpreter.

Comment: @MaximilianBurszley Is it not possible to configure the interpreter for language server separately in config file? It seems to not pass in parameters into the python, then how does it use the python binary?

Comment: Not as far as I know and they're planning on deprecating/removing the `pythonPath` configuration option for the vscode extension while muting criticisms.

Comment: Hmm I found something related to this in a Github [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/309), just adding it here for reference.

Comment: I tried Pylance as the language server and atleast got the basic code completion working! But it doesn't recognize the pip modules installed inside the container though. Nonetheless, it's still a big relief that the basic stuff works!